# Set Constraint to UITableViewCell related to UiViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I want to add UITableViewCells Height constraint equal to another View which is named as the Header View

In My SuperView I have a HeaderView on top. I have set its height constraint as 1/10 to my superView.

I have a UITableView in which there is a UITableViewCell.
1. Set the height constraint of the UITableViewCell in a ratio of 1/10 to the superview.
or 
2. Set the height constraint equal to HeaderView.

Can i add a constraint on the Interface Builder from my UITableViewCell to the Header View or the superview?

Comment: no, you have to set rowHeight property from code

Comment: You can't set constraint between TableViewCell and other view which are outside of the cell. You can do this by setting constraints programatically.

Comment: Hey @ techloverr , I want the rowHeight property to be in a ratio with the screen sizes. So what should i do?

Comment: you have set that with HeaderView..set the rowHeight to HeaderView's height..

Comment: Do you want the row Height to be 1/10 of the screen height? @CloyMonis

Comment: Hey  @Bharat Modi besides setting constraints programatically is there some other way to do this.

Comment: Yes @Darth Vader , I want the row height 1/10 of the screen height.

Comment: You need to calculate the ratio as you want and return it as the height for your cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the row height to be 1/10 of the screen height like this

```
tableView.rowHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/10
```

Let me know if this is working

Comment: May the Force be with you. @CloyMonis

Answer (score 1):

You can't set constraints to height for either table cell or table header from storyboard.
You can use following functions to make the height 1/10 of superview for both header and table cell:

```
// For table header view

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGFloat height = <superview>.frame.size.height/10;
    return height;
}

// For table cell

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height = <superview>.frame.size.height/10;
    return height;
}
```